# How to exclude logs generated by maven dependencies in slf4j?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I am new to slf4j. I have written API automation scripts (Maven/TestNG project) using Apache HTTPClient and used slf4j for logging. When I run the automation scripts with log level DEBUG, there is a lot of logs generated by HTTPClient itself and my intended logs are buried in them. How to force slf4j to report only my automation logs and skip everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a little on which *Runtime* SLF4J implementation you are using.

**Example Logback**

In case your runtime library is [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) then the configuration file might look like this:

File: `logback.xml`

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="your-package-name" level="DEBUG" />

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

- Just showing the logging on the console, see the `ConsoleAppender`
- Update the `<logger>` attribute `name`, and enter your package name, the top of it. All sub packages will also get included.

PS: In case you're using log4j as the runtime dependency, the config is similar. But if so, please read [Reasons to prefer logback over log4j](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html)

Comment: Thanks @Verhegan. I would like to know, whether we can use maven GroupId and Artifact Id to apply similar filter rather than a package?

Comment: @VelGanesh You just can add the top of the relevant packages, like 'org.organisation.myproject' then all [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) instances create in classes in that pacakge and any deeper packages, will be included. Most of the time the jar contains 1 or 2 root packages entries. So only 1 or 2 logger entries in the above configuration will include all the Logger instances, of the jar (library).